# How to unit test for turning off request validation?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, request-validation

I'm new at this TDD thing but making a serious effort, so I'm hoping to get some feedback here.

I created a little web service to minify JavaScript, and everything was nice, with all my tests passing. Then I noticed a bug: if I tried to minify `alert('<script>');`, it would throw a `HttpRequestValidationException`.

So that's easy enough to fix. I'll just add `[AllowHtml]` to my controller. But what would be a good way to unit test that this doesn't happen in the future?

The following was my first thought:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Minify_DoesntChokeOnHtml()
{
    try
    {
        using (var controller = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MinifyController>())
        {
            return controller.Minify("alert('<script></script>');");
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        Assert.Fail("Request validation prevented HTML from existing inside the JavaScript.");
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work since I am just getting a controller instance and running methods on it, instead of firing up the whole ASP.NET pipeline.

What would be a good unit test for this? Maybe reflector on the controller method to see if the `[AllowHtml]` attribute is present? That seems very structural, and unlikely to survive a refactoring; something functional might make more sense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only two options:

**First**

Write *integration test* that hosts MVC in-proc or runs using browser (using Watin for instance) that will cover you scenario.

**Second**

Write *unit test* that will check that method is marked with needed attribute.

I would go with the first option.